# Continuity of function and ...?

Tags: calculus

I'm aware of what continuity is:

- A function is continuous in its domain.
- A function is continuous in $x=a$ if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$

Being said that, I don't understand what I have to do in this exercise:

"The function $f(x)=(2x+5)^2+x \sin(\pi x)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Find a finite interval where the equation $f(x)=10$ has a solution. Justify your answer. Why it has a solution in that interval?"

I understand that $f(x)=(2x+5)^2+x \sin(\pi x)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ because the funtion has the combination of polynomial and trigonometric funtion and its domain is $\mathbb{R}$. $f(x)=10$ is a constant function and the domain is also $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't understand what it does refer to when says to find an interval where $f(x)=10$ has a solution.

If someone can clarify me to see how to start here I will appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that you need to find an interval $I$ such that there exists $x_0 \in I$ so that $(2x_0+5)^2 + x_0 \sin(\pi x_0) = 10$.

Comment: Suppose you found point, $a$ where $f(a) < 10$  And suppose you found a point, $b$ where $f(b) > 10$.  As $f$ is continuous what can we say about whether $f(x) =10$ anywhere?

Comment: One possible is answer $[-5,0]$. Then you can show, that $(2x+5)^2 + x \sin(\pi x) - 10$ is is positive outside this interval and negative inside.

Comment: "f(x)=10 is a constant function and the domain is also R."  They aren't defining a second function.  the function is still $f(x) = (2x+5)^2 + x\sin (\pi x)$.  What the are claiming is there is a point $x_0$ (although the call the point a *value* $x$... not a *variable* $x$) where $f(x_0) = (2x_0 + 5)^2 + x_0 \sin(\pi x_0) =10$.  You aren't asked to solve for $x_0$ but to find an interval $(a,b)$ so that $x_0 \in (a,b)$.

Comment: ohhh ok get it now. So I must show it with the Intermediate Value Theorem that is has a solution or root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the say $f(x) =10$ they don't mean that $f$ is the constant function.  $f$ is still the function $(2x+5)^2 + x\sin (\pi x)$ but $x$ is a value where $f(x) = (2x+5)^2 + x\sin (\pi x)=10$.

They want you to approximate the value of that $x$ where $f(x) =10$.  But they don't expect you to solve it.  They expect you to find an interval $[a,b]$ for $a < x < b$.

Now using the definition of continuous can you do that.

Hint:  $f(0) = 5^2 + 0*\sin 0 = 25> 10$.  And $f(-1) = 3^2 - 3*\sin (-\pi) = 9-3*0=9 < 10$.

Now use Intermediate Value theorem.

Comment: I must use the Intermediate Value Theorem right?

Comment: Yep.... I wasn't sure if you knew the IVT.

Comment: yes... I just got lost suddenly. Thanks. <3

Answer (score 0):

In the first part, $f(x)=(2x+5)^2+x \sin(\pi x)$ is defining a function, but $f(x)=10$ is not. It's posing an equation, asking for a value of $x$ such that $f(x)$ (the $f$ defined previously) take the value of $10$.